# Java solution to CodeChef "Surgical Strikes" challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge, primes, taxicab-geometry

I've just recently completed this programming "challenge" called [surgical strikes](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DEM2019A):

> \$N\$ Indian Air Force fighter planes are located in different bases across the country. Each airbase is described by some integer coordinate \$(x,y)\$. The Air Force plans to do surgical strikes on a maximum of \$M\$ different targets in enemy territory (which are also described by cartesian coordinates) and then come back to the common main airbase at coordinate `(baseX,baseY)`.
>
> Each army base and the targets are recognised by a secret integer `ID`. The time taken for an aircraft to go from a base to a target is the prime factor of the Manhattan Distance between the base and the target that is just greater than the `ID` of the source base (In case the `ID` is greater than or equal to the largest prime factor, then consider the `ID` itself). Similarly, the time taken for an aircraft to go from a target to the main base is the prime factor of the Manhattan Distance between the target and the main base that is just greater than the `ID` of the target (In case the `ID` is greater than or equal to the largest prime factor, then consider the `ID` itself).
>
> Each Aircraft needs to leave the base, reach target and come back to the main base in a maximum time of `T`. One aircraft can go to only one target before going to the main base.
>
> Find the maximum number of targets that can be reached in the enemy territory.

Here's my solution, which is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/DotCharlie/SurgicalStrikes/tree/8cd503f9c25a969f4629ed610d3ebe01d155d0bc). I'm coming here looking for suggestions on how I can improve my conventions, structure, and etc.

```
package me.charlesmgrube.airforce_model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Application {

    private ArrayList<Location> targets = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private ArrayList<Location> bases = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private Location mainBase;

    private int numBases = 0;
    private int numTargets = 0;
    private int maxTime = 0;

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        boolean running = true;

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (running) {
            String read = null;
            try {
                read = bfr.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            if(data.size() != maxInputLines()) {
                data.add(read);
                
                if(data.size() == 1) {
                    String[] split = read.split(" ");
                    numBases = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                    numTargets = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                    maxTime = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                }
            } else {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size() ; i++) {
            if(i == 0) continue;
            if(i <= numBases) {
                String[] split = data.get(i).split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                int id = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                bases.add(new Location(x, y, id));
            } else if (i > numBases && i <= numTargets+numBases) {
                String[] split = data.get(i).split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                int id = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                targets.add(new Location(x, y, id));
            } else {
                String[] split = data.get(i).split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                mainBase = new Location(x, y, -1);
            }
        }
        
        ArrayList<Integer> times = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int x = 0; x < bases.size(); x++) {
            int quickestTime = -1;
            for(int y = 0; y < targets.size(); y++) {
                int time = timeElapsed(bases.get(x), targets.get(y)) + timeElapsed(targets.get(y), mainBase);
                if(time < quickestTime || quickestTime==-1) {
                    quickestTime = time;
                }
            }
            times.add(quickestTime);
        }
        
        times.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        int num = 0;
        int totalTime = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
            if(totalTime + times.get(i) <= maxTime) {
                num++;
                totalTime += times.get(i);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    
    private int timeElapsed(Location loc1, Location loc2) {
        int manhattanDistance = Math.abs(loc2.getX() - loc1.getX()) + Math.abs(loc2.getY() - loc1.getY());
        List<Integer> factors = primeFactorization(manhattanDistance);
        factors.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        int factor = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++) {
            if(factors.get(i) > loc1.getId()) {
                factor = i;
            }
        }
        if(factor == -1) factor = loc1.getId();
        return 0;
    }

    private List<Integer> primeFactorization(int n) {
        int num = n;
        ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            while (num % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                num /= i;
            }
        }

        if (num > 1) {
            factors.add(num);
        }
        return factors;
    }

    private int maxInputLines() {
        return numTargets + numBases + 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().run();
    }
}
```

Location class:

```
package me.charlesmgrube.airforce_model;

public class Location {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int id;
    
    public Location(int x, int y, int id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Referential immutability

You don't reassign your lists - `targets` and `bases` - so make them `final`.

### Type weakening

So far as I can see, you aren't doing anything in your class that requires reference to the `ArrayList` methods of `targets` and `bases`. You should weaken them to `Collection`, or maybe `List` depending on some of your index-dependent loops. Also, omit the generic type during construction. So:

```
private final Collection<Location> targets = new ArrayList<>();
private final Collection<Location> bases = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
Collection<Integer> times = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Loop sanitization

This should go away if possible:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < data.size() ; i++) {
> ```

Just use three separate loops, i.e.

```
int i = 1;
for (; i <= numBases; i++) // ...
for (; i <= numTargets + numBases; i++) // ...
for (; i < data.size(); i++) // ...
```

and these:

> ```
>     for(int x = 0; x < bases.size(); x++) {
>         for(int y = 0; y < targets.size(); y++) {
> ```

should just be

```
for (Location base: bases) {
    for (Location target: targets) {
```

and

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
> ```

should just be

```
for (Integer time: times) {
```

### Class methods

This:

> ```
> private int timeElapsed(Location loc1, Location loc2) {
>     int manhattanDistance = Math.abs(loc2.getX() - loc1.getX()) + Math.abs(loc2.getY() - loc1.getY());
>     List<Integer> factors = primeFactorization(manhattanDistance);
>     factors.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
>     int factor = -1;
>     for(int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++) {
>         if(factors.get(i) > loc1.getId()) {
>             factor = i;
>         }
>     }
>     if(factor == -1) factor = loc1.getId();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

definitely belongs as a method on `Location`, either static accepting two locations, or where `loc1` is implied as `this`.

Make `primeFactorization` a static method.

### Location mutability

Your habit is to do the "standard Java thing" and make `set` methods for all of your members - but you should really only do so if you need to mutate your locations, which you absolutely don't. Delete all of your `set` methods.

You should also make a convenience constructor on `Location` that accepts a `String` and does this code for you:

```
            String[] split = data.split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
```

Comment: what's the advantages of making variables `final`?

Comment: Good question! Adding `final` allows the Java optimizer additional opportunities to optimize. Also, it makes your code more predictable and testable - if a thing is guaranteed to never change during its lifetime, you don't need to test it for changes.

Comment: thank you sm for the answer! I am curious though, why should I get rid of generic type in my construction and weaken the type to Collection?

Comment: Lose repetition of the generic type for brevity. Weaken your type so that you can change the implementation of a data structure without having to change the code that uses it. There's a principle in object oriented programming where code that uses a class should have the minimum amount of knowledge and access to that class.